# The controller does not update the text of the label

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I use the following code to create a custom view and add it to the contentView of a UICollectionViewCell

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell* newcell;// = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] init];

    newcell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"hi" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    TT2TimeViewController* controller = [[TT2TimeViewController alloc] init];

    NSString* city = [cities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    controller.city = city;
    UIView* view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TT2TimeViewController"
                                                  owner:controller
                                                options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    [newcell.contentView addSubview:view];
    return newcell;
}
```

In the xib of the TT2TimeViewController, I have placed a UILabel in the center and want the controller to update the label text to the value of the `city` variable.

However for some reason the label is not updated as expected. I have double-checked and ensured the IBOutlet is created and valid.

[image]

This is the code of the controller class TT2TimeViewController:

```
#import "TT2TimeViewController.h"

@implementation TT2TimeViewController


-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [self.lblCity setText:[self city]];
}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.lblCity setText:[self city]];
}
```

Neither functions is called.

One more screen shot to show how the file owner is set:

[image]

So my question is: Have I done anything wrong in the implementation of the function `collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`?

Comment: did you try awakeFromNib?

Comment: @santhu tried but did not work

Comment: Have you verified that self.lblCity is not NULL? Your  IB screenshot shows that it is connected to something, but are you sure it's connected to the correct instance of the class? Does a breakpoint in awakeFromNib: get hit? If it does, then all of the IB connections should be valid, so if the ivar is NULL at this breakpoint then it is not connected properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution: I need to link the 'view' variable of the controller to the view object in the xib file, like so:

[image]

Then it starts to work.

(The odd thing is: only `viewDidAppear` get called)